# jexcel not working

Tags: javascript, jsp, jxl

the following jsp code is not generating any excel file. Please help. Or can someone tell me other way to export table data from jsp/javascript to excel sheet?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page language="java" import="pack.DbBean"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"  %>
<%@ page import="jxl.*"  %>
<%@ page import="jxl.write.*"  %>

<%@ page import="jxl.Workbook"  %>
<%@ page import="jxl.write.Label"  %>
<%@ page import="jxl.write.WritableSheet"  %>
<%@ page import="jxl.write.WritableWorkbook"  %>



<jsp:useBean id="db" class="pack.DbBean" scope="session"/>

<%
try{
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
Label label = new Label(0, 2, "A label record");
sheet.addCell(label);

jxl.write.Number number = new jxl.write.Number(3, 4, 3.1459);
sheet.addCell(number);

workbook.write();
workbook.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
      {
       throw new ServletException("Exception in Excel Sample Servlet", e);
      } finally
      {
       if (out != null)
        out.close();
      }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that would create the excel sheet, but there's nothing in your code that would send it back to the browser. If I recall correctly, you can get a handle to the output stream and send it yourself from a JSP, but that's really not a good solution. JSP pages were not meant to be used this way.

A servlet or a JAX-RS web service would be a better choice. You could generate the excel sheet, and then 'save' it to the output stream that is the response back to the client. Make sure to mind your Content-Type on the return.